# What does Background Geolocation in Ionic 2 / Cordova mean?

Tags: cordova, geolocation, ionic2

I am implementing geo tracking in my app. There is foreground and background geolocation. In all tutorials I read that the background tracking is for cases when the app is closed.

But what if the app runs but is not in the foreground? Which type of geolocation should I use?

I have noticed that when I use background geolocation my Android phone shows an icon in the status bar 'Background tracking: Enabled'. I have never seen this notification when using Uber or some other taxi app, although I am sure that they use background tracking. How do they do this?